# freetds.conf ignored in PHP 5.5.3 on Windows

Tags: php, windows, freetds, mssql-jdbc

I follow this link: https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP to install php_dblib.dll (it's FreeTDS compiled for Windows 64bit) in my PHP 5.5.3 on Windows 64bit successfully. The output of phpinfo() shows:

```
Environment

...
FREETDS d:\portable_sw\php-5.5.30-Win32-VC11-x64\conf
...
mssql

MSSQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Library version FreeTDS
...
```

It looks like PHP engine catchs where freetds.conf is and mssql library is installed ok. In my freetds.conf, I've defined a server name 'mydb' as:

```
[mydb]
    host = 10.18.1.11
    port = 1433
    client charset = cp950
    tds version = 7.0
```

But when I run a PHP script with following php statement in browser:

```
$conn = mssql_connect('mydb', 'myuid', 'mypwd') or mydie('open mydb failed!');
```

It just hangs there for a while and then browser displays:

```
Cannot connect to the website

Please make sure: 

- You have entered the correct URL. 
- You are connected to the Internet.
- Your firewall is properly configured.
- The website is not encountering any technical problem at the moment.

Error code 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

If I change 'mydb' to '10.18.1.11', it connects ok. It seems the setting in freetds.conf is ignored. What could be the cause and how do I solve it?

Comment: Try sqlsrv, native SQL Server driver for PHP on Windows: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: I also use sqlsrv. But in this case, I have a bunch of old PHP programs that already use mssql_* function to access a MSSQL 7.0 server. That's why I stick with mssql library here.

Comment: Can you change `$conn = mssql_connect('mydb', 'myuid', 'mypwd') or mydie('open mydb failed!');` to `$conn = mssql_connect('mydb', 'myuid', 'mypwd');` to see the actual error message? I'm not very familiar with FreeTDS on Windows, but is there an equivalent testing tool to `tsql`?

Comment: It doesn't show anything. In the error.log of httpd, it shows: `[Tue Jul 12 11:50:50.618293 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 260] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 13 2015 11:37:51` `[Tue Jul 12 11:50:50.618293 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4036:tid 260] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -d D:/portable_sw/httpd-2.4.17-win64-VC11'`
`[Tue Jul 12 11:50:50.621294 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 260] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5384`
`[Tue Jul 12 11:50:50.836306 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5384:tid 276] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.`.

Comment: Now even the IP-Address way doesn't work. I've use some mssql client tool to connect server, it's ok. So I'm sure it's the driver problem.

Comment: There's a one more error message: "child process 5384 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting."

Comment: Thanks for who give comment on my question. I finally give it up on Windows. My colleague makes a php 5.5.9 environment on CentOS. It connects mssql well. Freetds for PHP 5.5 on Windows is a disaster....ORZ.

Comment: I modify programs to use sqlsrv. It works well on Windows. For sqlsrv driver 3.2, we have to install both SQL Server Native Client 2012 and MS ODBC driver 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up mssql-* and use sqlsrv-*, it works well. So his question is answered by "ME".